# Error in generating pdflatex from Doxygen output

Tags: pdftex, texlive, warnings, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen in order to document my program.
The Doxygen create a lot of tex file and I'm using TeX Live in order to generate a pdf file from the tex files.

It has been worked before but now, after little changes in my source code there is compilation warnings of the latex and it fail to compile although there is no problem with the Doxygen documentation.

The new warnings are:

```
`LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

And a lot of warnings like:

```
`LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 60 undefined on input line 170`.
```

The compilation end with:

```
make: *** [refman.pdf] Error 1
 exit code: 2(0 for SUCCESS).loggingLevel: 20. Build will exit.
```

I tried to rerun a few times and there isn't a change.
Can anyone help me with it?

edit:
This is my main tex file :

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

% Packages required by doxygen
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{doxygen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Font selection
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\allsectionsfont{%
  \fontseries{bc}\selectfont%
  \color{darkgray}%
}
\renewcommand{\DoxyLabelFont}{%
  \fontseries{bc}\selectfont%
  \color{darkgray}%
}

% Page & text layout

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,%
  top=2.5cm,%
  bottom=3.5cm,%
  left=2.5cm,%
  right=2.5cm,%
  headheight=2.5cm%
}
\tolerance=750
\hfuzz=15pt
\hbadness=750
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{15pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0ex}{-1.0ex}{1.0ex}{%
    \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@parafont%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{0ex}{-1.0ex}{1.0ex}{%
    \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@subparafont%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Headers & footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{doxygen-logo-header.jpg}}
\rhead{Page \thepage  \ of\ \pageref{LastPage}}
\chead{\fancyplain{}{massage}}
\lfoot{\fancyplain{}{massage2}}
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{massage3}}
\rfoot{\fancyplain{}{massage4}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\thesection\ #1}%
}

% Indices & bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\makeindex

% Hyperlinks (required, but should be loaded last)
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[ps2pdf,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
  unicode%
}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}%
}


%===== C O N T E N T S =====

\begin{document}

% Titlepage & ToC

\pagestyle{empty}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{7cm}
\begin{center}%
\includegraphics{doxygen-logo-pdf.jpg}\\[1cm]
{\Huge Library Reference }\\
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large COMPANY}\\
{\large VERSION }\\
\vspace*{1cm}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\tableofcontents
\clearemptydoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%--- Begin generated contents ---
\chapter{Module Index}
\input{modules}
\chapter{Data Structure Index}
\input{annotated}
\chapter{File Index}
\input{files}
\chapter{Module Documentation}
\input{group}
\chapter{Data Structure Documentation}
\input{struct}
\chapter{File Documentation}
\input{file}

%--- End generated contents ---

% Index
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

It seems like the problem is in the Page & text layout, if I change the "bottom=3.5cm,%" to be "bottom=2.5cm,%" it works.
I don't know if that was the problem or this only a way to work around the real problem, I'm looking for a long time solution because my source files change frequently and I don't want to change the tex file every time.

I will be glad to here if you find problems in my tex file or have an idea to the cause of my problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It is hard to tell what the problem might be without seeing the LaTeX source. Do you have the `.tex` files available? If yes, then you could try to minimize them (i.e., remove content step by step) and try to recompile every time you have removed something until the error disappears, then try to remove more code from before that, until you have the smallest possible file that show the problem. Once you have found that you can post it here.

Comment: That will probably point you to the location in your Doxygen code that is responsible for the error as well. From there, you could try to make a minimal Doxygen example that shows the error, then post that as well.

Comment: If you don't have access to the `.tex` file then it is a bit harder, but still you can try to remove parts of the code that are unrelated to what you have added last (which presumably causes the error, since it compiled without problems before) and create a minimal Doxygen example in that way.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using and which version of TexLive? after you have build the tex files with doxygen how are you trying to build the resulting pdf?

Comment: I edited the problem with my tex file, I use Doxygen - 1.8.5
 and TexLive 2020

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.5 is a bit old (August 23, 2013) and you are using a new version of TexLive. So there are  a number of possible problems. 1) A certainty is the problem with the tabu package (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6769 and https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu). In doxygen a workaround has been created in version 1.8.16. 2) There might have been problems in the specific 1.8.5 codethat have been fixed in the mean time. So the advise is to upgrade doxygen to a newer version (1.8.20).